# What is the encoding of the string returned from Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi?

Tags: c#, encoding, marshalling

I'm implementing a custom Marshaler, to send the utf8 string from/to native from/to managed.

```
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class UTF8StringMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
    {
        private static ICustomMarshaler marshalerInstance = new UTF8StringMarshaler();

        public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string optionalCookie)
        {
            return marshalerInstance;
        }
        public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
        {
            //Managed Data will be deleted by the garbage collector
        }

        public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pNativeData);
        }

        public int GetNativeDataSize()
        {
            //Not used in our case
            return -1;
        }

        public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
        {
            if (ManagedObj == null || ManagedObj as string == null)
                return IntPtr.Zero;

            if (!(ManagedObj is string))
                throw new MarshalDirectiveException("UTF8StringMarshaler can only be used on String.");

            UTF8Encoding utf8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            string utf8string = ManagedObj as string;
            byte[] stringBuffer = utf8Encoder.GetBytes(utf8string);
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(stringBuffer.Length + 1);
            Marshal.Copy(stringBuffer, 0, buffer, stringBuffer.Length);
            Marshal.WriteByte(buffer + stringBuffer.Length, 0);
            return buffer;
        }

        public unsafe object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
            if (pNativeData == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;
            string temp = null;
            UTF8Encoding utf8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
            byte* buffer = (byte*)pNativeData;
            while (*buffer != 0)
            {
                buffer++;
            }
            int length = (int)(buffer - (byte*)pNativeData);

            byte[] stringbuffer = new byte[length];

            Marshal.Copy(pNativeData, stringbuffer, 0, length);
            try
            {
                temp = utf8Encoder.GetString(stringbuffer);
            }
            catch (EncoderFallbackException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encoding Exception type {0}, Error {1}", e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

This implementation works except when the C# string is from `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` function.

so in `MarshalNativeToManaged` function, I need to verify if the string is the right encoding from the `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`

From the Microsoft Doc, `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` widens each ANSI character to Unicode:

`Copies all characters up to the first null character from an unmanaged ANSI string to a managed String, and widens each ANSI character to Unicode.`

So the question is, what is the Encoding of the string from `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` function?

Is there a simpler way to verify if the string is from that function?

Comment: It depends on your viewer.  An ANSI string is one byte ([byte[]) characters terminated with a zero ('\0').  ASCII characters are from 0x00 to 0xFF where characters are the same for all encoding from 0x00 to 0x7FF.  Encoding displays the character from 0x80 to 0xFF differently (depending on language and region of the world).  If you are not getting an exception than you code is good but your viewer is not the same as the encoding method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the Encoding of the string from Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi function?

There is no one "ANSI" encoding. It is whatever the current code page of your system is. It will depend on the user's locale settings. This should correspond to the [`CharSet` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset):

> **Ansi**: Marshal strings as multiple-byte character strings: the system default Windows (ANSI) code page on Windows, and UTF-8 on Unix.

Note the special handling on Unix though (and on, I presume, Linux).

> Is there a simpler way to verify if the string is from that function?

That seems to me to be a completely different question from what appears to be the main one. In particular: knowing what encoding the function will use when converting from "ANSI" to UTF-16 (the internal text encoding used by .NET) doesn't seem to me to lead to a way to *"verify if the string is from that function"*. Once you have a C# `string` object, it's already been encoded as UTF-16. It could have originated from practically *any* encoding.

It's also not clear from your question what you mean by *"works except when the C# string is from `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` function"*. That is, in what way *precisely* does it not work under that scenario? Your marshaler appears to be responsible for nothing more than passing UTF-8 bytes to or from the native code. Given a C# `string` object, it should never matter how that `string` was created. It is now a string of UTF-16 characters, which can be reliably re-encoded as UTF-8. If there's a problem with "ANSI" text, that problem occurred before your marshaler got involved. Your marshaler shouldn't have to concern itself with that.

Finally: why not just use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of instantiating a new `UTF8Encoding` object on every marshaling operation? At the very least, you should be caching the object, but since `GetBytes()` and `GetString()` work the same for any instance of `UTF8Encoding`, really you should just use the one that .NET has already created for you, and let .NET deal with caching the object.